# Why the center of circle is dark in this interference experiment?

Tags: optics, waves, interference

As the image you can see, a lens with focus length of $f$ was cut into 2 parts, L1 and L2, a distance of $f$ between them. A monochromatic point source of light $S$ was put in the left of L1 with a distance of $f$. It's not hard to know that two individual ray from the source will pass through respectively upper half lens and lower half lens. Thus, the two rays will interference with each other somewhere in the right of L2. Let's say they will interference on a surface M, where interference fringes are a series of concentric circles(obviously).

[image]

**The question is why the center of circle is dark?** Usually the two rays pass through the center of two half lenses, then the optical path difference should be $0$, which indicates the center of circle should be bright instead of dark. The answer gives a tip which says when a ray passes through the image point, it will have a phase shift of $\pi$, then cause the center dark. But I still don't understand how this come.

Comment: _"interference fringes are a series of concentric circles(obviously)"_ — it's not really obvious. The system doesn't have cylindrical symmetry, so I don't think you'll get concentric circles. Or, at least, they'll be quite distorted.

Comment: It is not an experiment, ( found none) it is a problem in  geometrical optics.